# HTML table manipulation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, cakephp, html-table

I'm building a site using CakePHP and am currently working on adding data to two separate tables at the same time.. not a problem.

The problem I have is that I'm looking to dynamically alter the form that accepts the input values, allowing the click of a button/link to add an additional row of form fields.

At the moment I have a table that looks something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Campus</th>
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="FulltimeCourseCampusCode0CampusId" name="data[FulltimeCourseCampusCode][0][campus_id]">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">Evesham</option>
                <option value="2">Malvern</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="FulltimeCourseCampusCode0CourseCode" name="data[FulltimeCourseCampusCode][0][course_code]">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I need is for the row within the tbody tag to be replicated, with the minor change of having all the zeros (i.e. such as here

```
FulltimeCourseCampusCode0CampusId
```

and here

```
data[FulltimeCourseCampusCode][0][campus_id]
```

) incremented.

I'm very new to jQuery, having done a few minor bits, but nothing this advanced (mostly just copy/paste stuff).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a plugin for jQuery that might help you, it's simple to use.
http://boriscy.github.com/grider/

Comment: Hi, thank you - the documentation you have is a little bit confusing, but I got it working, so thank you. PS, the links you have on the site don't work, I had to navigate myself to http://github.com/boriscy/grider to find the download.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$('#add').click(function() {

    var index = $('table tbody tr').last().index() + 1;
    var tr = $('table tbody tr').first().clone();

    tr.find('select')
      .attr('id', 'FulltimeCourseCampusCode' + index + 'CampusId')
      .attr('name', 'data[FulltimeCourseCampusCode][' + index + '][campus_id]');
    tr.find('input')
      .attr('id', 'FulltimeCourseCampusCode0CourseCode')
      .attr('name', 'data[FulltimeCourseCampusCode][' + index + '][course_code]');

    $('table tbody').append(tr);

    return false;

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I could not get it working, probably my own fault however, still need to learn a lot about jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that returns the HTML (as a string or a DOM tree) but give it a parameter for the index.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you execute the following every time the user clicks the add button. But no guarantee (untested written in 1min)

```
var rows = $("table tbody tr");
var first rows.eq(0);
first.clone().appendTo($("table tbody")).find("*[id^=FulltimeCourseCampusCode]").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.attr("id", $this.attr("id").replace("0", rows.size()));
  $this.attr("name", $this.attr("name").replace("0", rows.size()));
})
```